# Printing arrays on masm?

Tags: assembly

```
.model tiny
.486
.data
dat1    db  12h,13h,14h,15h
term    db  '$'
.code
.startup
    lea dx,dat1
    mov     ah,09h
    int     21h
.exit
end
```

[image]

*this is the output i am getting*
*if i place a string instead of array it work fine*

I tried to print the array shown to my dosbox terminal.

Comment: int 21/09 only prints strings. You need to convert to text.

Comment: Except for printing strings, there's nothing that will print arrays, so just print one element at a time in a loop.